# XRAY_Can we map one robot test case with multiple tags(multiple test cases in Jira) using Xray

Tags: python, robotframework, jira-xray

Xray:I have one robot test case that covers multiple test cases in Jira. Is it possible to execute one test script and update multiple test cases with passed or failed status in Jira using Xray

Below is the robot test case that has multiple test cases i.e. CS-28, CS-628 and i want to update the status of both in Jira with the help of XRAY

Verify the Conport button is present for smb customers

**[Tags]    CS-28    CS-628**

Given I am logged in to salesforce service console

And I have verified account with BAN as "1234567448"

Then I should see the Conport button present beside products button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz1IV.png)

Answer (score 0):

A RF (Robot Framework) test case can only be linked to a Xray Test issue, because a Test in Xray is precisely a test case.
I highly advise you to have different RF test cases, each one having a specific purpose. In terms of Xray, of couse this would also be mapped to different Test issues.
Note that a .robot file (i.e. a suite) can have multiple RF test cases, and each one can be linked to its own Test in Xray.

Comment: So does that means, one test case(not suite) could only be mapped to one test case in Jira using xray

Comment: exactly @AnkitaVermA

Comment: you're welcome @AnkitaVermA; nevertheless, it would be interesting for me to understand exactly your use case. If possible, can you briefly share an example of a RF test case and why you would like to map it to more than one Test issue? maybe with a concrete example it can be easier to understand

Comment: so the requirement is, sometimes we create single automation test script that covers multiple Test Cases in Jira, eg, there is one test case in Jira that says "Verify the button should be present" and 2nd test case says, "Validate on clicking button, it redirects to some link". So these are two different test cases but while automating, I have created one test script that covers both the validations. In such types of scenarios, XRAY will update the status for only one test case(first tag for RF) and the second one will not be updated. I hope I was clear.